Homotopy group of a wedge sum of CW complexes.
I am stuck on the following exercise in Homotopical Topology by Fomenko and Fuchs [Exercise 11.1]:

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are $p$-connected and $q$-connected CW complexes, respectively, where $p,q\geq 1$. Prove that $\pi_{p+q+1}(X\vee Y)$ is isomorphic to $\pi_{p+1}(X)\oplus\pi_{q+1}(Y)\oplus[\pi_{p+1}(X)\otimes\pi_{q+1}(Y)]$ where the last summand is embedded as $\alpha\otimes\beta\mapsto[i_*\alpha,j_*\beta]$ where $[.,.]$ is the Whitehead product and $i,j$ are inclusions of $X,Y$ into $X\vee Y$.

I was thinking of considering the natural inclusion map $\pi_{p+q+1}(X\vee Y)\to\pi_{p+q+1}(X\times Y)\cong\pi_{p+1}(X)\oplus\pi_{q+1}(Y)$ and show that the kernel is the tensor product above. We can assume $X,Y$ have only 1 vertex and do not have cells of dimension lower than $p+1,q+1$ respectively. And it suffices to consider the $(p+q+2)$-skeleton of $X\times Y$ which would be $X\vee Y$ with $(p+q+2)$-product cells attached.
And then... I don't know how to continue. Now, in the simplest case where $X,Y$ are just spheres, I see that the Whitehead products are just the attachment of the product cell and it can be contracted into the cell. But we are dealing with a bouquet of such product cells which I am not sure how to deal with (which is where I assume the tensor product comes in?), not to mention all the other cells left in $X\vee Y$. Please pardon my really poor understanding, any help or hint would be appreciated!

Here's a sketch as to one way of proving this: The pair sequence of $(X\times Y,X\vee Y)$ has a canonical splitting, which reduces this to showing that the cross product (related to the Whitehead product via the boundary map) $\pi_{p+1}(X)\otimes\pi_{q+1}(Y)\rightarrow\pi_{p+q+2}(X\times Y,X\vee Y)$ is an isomorphism. There is a commutative square with this cross product, the cross product in homology, which is an isomorphism by the Künneth theorem, and the Hurewicz isomorphisms, and the result follows.
